# Dell N411z will not boot from usb

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, dell-inspiron

My friend upgraded her inspiron from windows 7 to windows 10 without checking to see if it was compatible. Now it is stuck in a boot loop and keeps restarting without loading. I purchased the Restore media for this model from dell and it arrived as a usb stick. The computer will not boot from usb. I have set the boot oreder correctly in the bios but still wont work. It will boot from disc. Can i fix this problem or make a bootable disc set from the Dell usb stick?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is try to boot the USB on another machine. If it boots then you know the issue is isolated to the PC and not a bad USB drive. Also double check the boot order of the USB in the BIOS just in case the settings weren't saved when adjusted.

Usually any Dell Windows 7 image will work to boot your machine. Download one and burn to a CD/DVD as a last resort.

Comment: Can you provide specifics?

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I loaded an old copy of windows xp on it then updated the bios. It still would not work. I then reset the bios to the default settings and put usb at the top of the boot order.  Worked like a champ.